# Give the error of command inside timeout

Tags: linux, bash, shell, timeout

I'm using the timeout function on gnome to wait 1 second for my script which read input from inp.txt. I need to write the output of the script to out.txt so i code like this

```
timeout 1 myscript < inp.txt > out.txt
```

The problem i have is, if myscript failed (segmentation fault, etc), it prints the error to the screen. 
I want to keep those messages in something like Error.log, but i don't figure out how to do this.
I've tried

```
timeout 1 myscript < inp.txt > out.txt 2> Error.log
```

But it gives me this instead of the error of myscript.

```
timeout: the monitored command dumped core
```

Comment: This works for me without output: `(set +m; timeout 5 sleep 5 > out.txt 2> Error.log &); sleep 2; killall -QUIT sleep`

Comment: thanks, your solution keeps the message after the timeout which is useful.
Btw, adding --preserve-status is a good choice, which gives me the exitcode and i just have to search for it later.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subshell with quoted arguments to wrap the redirects, so that `timeout` doesn't see them:

```
timeout --preserve-status 1  sh -c 'exec myscript < inp.txt > out.txt 2> Error.log'
```